# How to Add Logic to Kustomize File

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am trying to deploy a K8s application using Kustomize. Up to now I have done simple implementations where we have a few of the K8s files such as `ingress.yaml` with something like the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingressname
  namespace: namespace
  labels:
    app: appname  
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - $(variable1) 
      secretName: $(variable2)-tls
```

Under my `overlays` directory for each environment, I then have another `kustomize.yaml` which gives the values in a configmap:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- path

configMapGenerator:
- behavior: merge
  literals:
  - variable1=foo
  - variable2=bar
  name: configmapname
images:
- name: imagename
  newName: registryurl
```

This works well, but now I need to do something more complicated. Say for example I have multiple ingress. Instead of creating multiple base ingress yaml files, how can I have one base yaml file that creates every ingress based on the values in my overlay file? Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kustomize isn't a templating system and doesn't do variable substitution. It *can* perform a variety of YAML patching tricks, so one option you have is to start with a base manifest like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingressname
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts: []
      secretName:
```

And then patch it in your `kustomization.yaml` files:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../base

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Ingress
      name: ingressname
    patch: |
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/tls
        value:
          - hosts:
              - host1.example.com
            secretName: host1-tls
```

What I've shown here works well if you have an application consisting of a single Ingress and you want to produce multiple variants (maybe one per cluster, or per namespace, or something). That is, you have:

- A Deployment
- A Service
- An Ingress
- (etc.)

Then you would have one directory for each variant of the app, giving you a layout something like:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
└── overlays
    ├── variant1
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── variant2
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

If your application has *multiple* Ingress resources, and you want to apply the same patch to all of them, [Kustomize can do that](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/patchMultipleObjects.md). If you were to modify the patch in your `kustomization.yaml` so that it looks like this instead:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../base

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Ingress
      name: ".*"
    patch: |
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/tls
        value:
          - hosts:
              - host1.example.com
            secretName: host1-tls
```

This would apply the same patch to all matching Ingress resources (which is "all of them", in this case, because we used `.*` as our match expression).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if you can list multiple `kind` in the overlay `kustomization.yaml` file?

Comment: I think you'll need a separate patch for each `kind` (my gut instinct is that it would be unusual for a patch to apply correctly to more than one resource types, and for common attributes like labels and annotations there are other facilites in kustomize for setting those things).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to do what I needed by adding a section for each kind (ingress, deployment, etc.). `kustomize build .` in the overlay directory shows the yaml files are how I need them.

Comment: I had one follow-up question. What if I need to create several yamls each with a different name? For example, say I have one service named `product` and one service named `price`. Is there a way to do this with a patch in the overlay on a single base `service.yaml` file?